# How do I switch off dynamic schema support?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

Microsoft recommends to switch off dynamic schema support before publishing an app:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj193175.aspx

> Important: We recommend that you disable dynamic schema support before publicly releasing your app.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic schema is only available with Javascript/Node backend.  In the portal, click on the Configure tab and you see an option to turn on/off dynamic schema.

Comment: I only use .NET and my schema is dynamic as well. When I add a new entity and the right table exists, it is automatically created. This video shows how to do it in a previous version/setting of Azure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3O7eFwyiS8Q . You need the data tab first (which I do not see).

Comment: Dynamic schema means that if you update your table with an entity that does have a field that does not exist in the database, the backend will create that field automatically for you.  There's no Data tab is you're using a .NET backend.